# Maven is not showing the arguments for parameterized tests, what could be wrong?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

The tests appear to be running fine (well some are failing, but they're running), but the log isn't showing me the parameters, why?

```java
@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@ContextConfiguration(
    locations = {
        "classpath:spring/testContext.xml",
        "classpath:applicationContext-mock.xml"
    } )
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles( Profiles.TEST )
@Category( IntegrationTest.class )
public abstract class AbstractDalTestBase {
```

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ArgumentsSource(LetterSearchWithFilterAndPagingForHCPCSCodeArguments.class)
    public void letterSearchWithFilterAndPagingForHCPCSCode(String searchTerm, int expected) {
        List<?> results = findMatchingItemsWithFilterAndPaging(searchTerm, CatalogItemType.HCPCSCODE, 0, 0, null);
        int projection = loadTotalNumberOfItems(searchTerm, CatalogItemType.HCPCSCODE);
        assertThat(projection).as("projection eq results").isEqualTo(results.size());
        assertThat(projection).as("projection eq expected").isEqualTo(expected);
        assertThat(results.size()).as("results eq expected").isEqualTo(expected);
    }
```

```java
class LetterSearchWithFilterAndPagingForHCPCSCodeArguments implements ArgumentsProvider {

    @Override
    public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        int count = 5643;
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("A", count),
            Arguments.of("a"),
            Arguments.of("b", 2151)
        );
    }
}
```

```
[ThreadedStreamConsumer] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin - letterSearchWithFilterAndPagingForHCPCSCode{String, int}[1]  Time elapsed: 2.496 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: 
[projection eq results] 
Expecting:
 <5643>
and actual:
 <5643>
to refer to the same object
```

I thought junit was supposed to log the values passed to the method, how can I make it do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Surefire plugin probably can't do much with this: JUnit5 does not seem to expose test case arguments information on running/ending the test, but provides a display name for a particular test, and the name contains the test run ordinal and `toString`-ed arguments passed to the test, like `[ORDINAL] ARG1, ARG2...` (that one that appears in IntelliJ IDEA JUnit runner). However, the Surefire plugin does not parse such names (for whatever reason, as they may probably change in the future?), or simply ignores them under some circumstances.

Here is a sample test (`@MethodSource` does not seem to affect the outcome):

```java
public final class FooTest {

    private static Stream<? extends Arguments> test() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(1, 1),
                Arguments.of(1, 0)
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    public void test(final Object a, final Object b) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(a, b);
    }

}
```

The above test fails with the following assertion failure under `maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5`:

```
[ERROR] FooTest.test(Object, Object)[2]  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <0>
    at FooTest.test(FooTest.java:31)
```

I checked out the current 3.0.6-SNAPSHOT source code, and applied the following patch (on top of `be236f772724aab93087c82b84ef484e2e0bfa80`), then updating the Surefire version to 3.0.0-M6-SNAPSHOT in the test `pom.xml`:

```
From 9b01ccc020c5c2040ef0ee6988f5faa2d179a1db Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: - <->
Date: Wed, 6 Jan 2021 02:53:27 +0200
Subject: [PATCH] Append test arguments to the method description

---
 .../maven/surefire/junitplatform/RunListenerAdapter.java     | 5 +++++
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+)

diff --git a/surefire-providers/surefire-junit-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitplatform/RunListenerAdapter.java b/surefire-providers/surefire-junit-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitplatform/RunListenerAdapter.java
index b193ba5ed..8af18c110 100644
--- a/surefire-providers/surefire-junit-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitplatform/RunListenerAdapter.java
+++ b/surefire-providers/surefire-junit-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitplatform/RunListenerAdapter.java
@@ -287,6 +287,11 @@ private StackTraceWriter toStackTraceWriter( String realClassName, String realMe
             boolean hasLegacyDescription = description.startsWith( methodName + '(' );
             boolean hasDisplayName = !equalDescriptions || !hasLegacyDescription;
             String methodDesc = equalDescriptions || !hasParams ? methodSign : description;
+            int argsPos = display.indexOf( "] " );
+            if ( argsPos != -1 )
+            {
+                methodDesc += "  (" + display.substring( argsPos + 2 ) + ')';
+            }
             String methodDisp = hasDisplayName ? display : methodDesc;
 
             // The behavior of methods getLegacyReportingName() and getDisplayName().
-- 
2.30.0
```

And then installed the patched version to my local repository using `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install`. Now the assertion failure becomes like this:

```
[ERROR] FooTest.test(Object, Object)[2]  (1, 0)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <0>
    at FooTest.test(FooTest.java:31)
```

where   `(1, 0)`, the test arguments, now appear right after the test name.

I guess you have to raise a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE so that the maintainers could improve the parameterized test names support if it's possible (not sure if it requires JUnit improvements as well).

Comment: Actually, I found a junit ticket, and the problem is surefire. It is fixed in 3.0 M4 (which I can't use). If you look at Gradle you'll see it works fine there. I'll update tomorrow with more details

Comment: updated my answer to include all relevant details

Answer (score 1):

I found [this JUnit ticket](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/990), and the problem is surefire. It is fixed in [3.0.0-M5](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Surefire_Extensions_and_Reports_Configuration_for_.40DisplayName) which, unfortunately, I can't use.

> The rationale behind not using display names is that it would "break" the XML report generated by Surefire. Thus, we need a new reporting format and Surefire needs to adopt it before we can report display names (cf. #373).

> Since plugin version 3.0.0-M4 you can use fine grained configuration of reports and enable phrased names together with @DisplayName in you tests. This is the complete list of attributes of particular objects. You do not have to specify e.g. disable, version and encoding. The boolean values reach default values false if not specified otherwise.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                    <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
                </statelessTestsetReporter>
                <consoleOutputReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5ConsoleOutputReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                </consoleOutputReporter>
                <statelessTestsetInfoReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                    <usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>true</usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>
                    <usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>true</usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>
                </statelessTestsetInfoReporter>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I am a developer of Surefire. Nothing would be broken with XML because the strings are escaped. Commenting the https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/990